# How to compute the K-group of this affine scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, k-theory

By Bott periodicity, we know that $$K_{0}^{top}(S^2)=\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$$ But $S^2$ is defined by the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. If we write this abstractly as $$X:=Spec\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2-1) ,$$ then how can we compute $$K_{0}^{alg}(X)$$ the $K_0$ is the same definition as Hartshorne's Ex II.6.10

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the K0 of that spectrum? Are you looking at the usual topological K0 built out of reall  vector bundles on the spec with its Zariski topology?

Comment: The usual topology on that spec is **not** the one coming from R^3...

Comment: It should be algebraic K-theory,but I am not familiar with it, yet. It is an analogy: S^2 is in R^3, so we  consider R[x,y,z] instead of C[x,y,z]

Comment: Do you not mean $K_0$ in the sense of $K_0$ on the category of coherent modules?

Comment: It means as Hartshorne‘s Ex II.6.10

Comment: Please edit the question and make it be very explicit about what you mean. As you see, there are many possibilities, and the answers to each are correspondingly different!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The algebraic K-theory of smooth affine or projective quadrics is quite well understood (as opposed to their Chow groups). There is a nice paper of Swan called K-theory of quadric hypersurfaces, where not only the $K_0$ but also the higher $K_i$ are computed in term of the K-theory of the base ring. You will see that it also depends on the Clifford algebra of the quadratic form.

This paper also consider the $K_0$ of spheres over $\mathbb{R, C}$ and $\mathbb{H}$. This is theorem 3. It shows that there is a one to one correspondence between stable classes of algebraic and topological vector bundles.

Hence, for the 2-sphere : $K_0^{alg}(\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2-1))=KO^0(S^2)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Note that you could have said that $S^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{CP}^1$ and ask for the algebraic K-theory of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$. In that case $K_0^{alg}(\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C})=K^0(S^2)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$